# Compare between two databases have the same tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper, dto

I have 2 databases, each of which has 2 tables, `Employee` and `Department`.

One of them is old and the other one is the new one.

I want to compare the data between them. I have make *DTOs* classes and mapping between entities and the DTOs classes using *Automapper*.

Can anyone help me step by step to compare these databases using EF?

1. Compare the data from old database to the new database.
2. Depending on the comparison show result in one of four groups:

   - Data already exist with no change
   - New data ready to be moved
   - Data to be updated
   - Data to be deleted
3. Then I can deploy the changes to the new database

Comment: Hi Gehad, have you written any code to start doing this? Before trying to get help on a problem, you should first make a reasonable attempt and then document what you've tried on your question.

Comment: Why do not you use **RedGate Sql Data Compare**?